# su inside bash script doesn't work

Tags: linux, bash, sudo, pulseaudio

I want to kill pulseaudio within a bash script that executed with sudo.
The problem is that command "pulseaudio -k" can not be used by root user.
I desided to switch user inside of script, to an unprivileged user who actually started pulseaudio server.

```
#!/bin/bash

su -c "pulseaudio -k" user_name
```

If I place everything to bash file and execute it,

```
sudo ./kill-pulseaudio.sh
```

I get an error:

```
E: [pulseaudio] core-util.c: XDG_RUNTIME_DIR (/run/user/1000) is not 
owned by us (uid 0), but by uid 1000! (This could e g happen if you 
try to connect to a non-root PulseAudio as a root user, over the 
native protocol. Don't do that.)
E: [pulseaudio] main.c: Failed to kill daemon: No such file or directory
```

But no errors if I just call the following command from terminal:

```
[user_name@host ~]$  su -c "pulseaudio -k" user_name
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try running the script with `sudo -E ...` to preserve the user environment.

Comment: IT WORKS!!! Thank you. Could you please give some short explanation why it works?

Comment: Sure, when you use `sudo` or `su`, you change to the new user (in your case `root`), and if you do not specify that the current user environment be preserved (e.g. the `.bashrc`, `.bash_profile`, etc.. settings), you get the environment for the user you are switching to. That may lack `path` and other necessary environment information. For `sudo`, the `-E` switch or for `su` the `-m, -p, --preserve-environment` switch(s) will preserve the current user environment. (including the current `XDG_RUNTIME_DIR` setting `:)`